# How is the readline() method called in this code?

Tags: python, overriding, stdout, sys, tee

I found this `Tee` code here on Stack Overflow and it works really well for logging an interactive python shell session. I understand OOP okay, however I am unsure as to: a) how methods are being called in this particular code. How does the method `readline()` get called?  b) And I read that `__del__` is pretty much the opposite of a constructor, but I am also confused as to when that is getting called as well.

```
import code
import sys

class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, log_fname, mode='a'):
        self.log = open(log_fname, mode)

    def __del__(self):
        # Restore sin, so, se
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        sys.stdir = sys.__stdin__
        sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
        self.log.close()

    def write(self, data):
        self.log.write(data)
        sys.__stdout__.write(data)

    def readline(self):
        s = sys.__stdin__.readline()
        self.log.write(s)
        return s

# Tie the ins and outs to Tee.
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = sys.stdin = Tee('consolelog.dat', 'w')
console = code.InteractiveConsole()
console.interact()
```

Comment: A link provided to where you found the code could be helpful.

Comment: Ah sorry. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053900/how-to-log-everything-that-occurs-in-a-python-interactive-shell-session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet is overriding standard in, standard out and standard error with a custom file-like object that implements the common protocol (`.write` and `.readline` in this case). `code.InteractiveConsole` uses `sys.stdin` etc. to for input and output, so by overriding them you are basically piping the stream into your object.

Comment: The question also asks how `__del__` is being called. It unhooks `sys.stdin/stdout/stderr` and closes the logfiles to shut down the tee'ing gracefully.

Comment: Ok I always thought the super method was needed for inheritance/overriding methods.... learned something new. That makes a lot more sense now

Comment: @swim Well no. In this case, you are overriding (modifying) specific properties of an instance i.e. `sys` to be specific. `Tee` does not inherit from anything except `object` (which is implicit in Python 3).

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

a) 
By default, `sys.stdin` is set to `sys.__stdin__`. When `input` or similar functions are called, `sys.stdin.readline` is called (which underneath is actually `sys.__stdin__.readline`)
When `sys.stdin` is set to an instance of `Tee`, `sys.stdin.readline` now calls `Tee.readline`.

b) Its called deconstructor and is called when the object is freed from memory. Usually the garbage collector does this when there is no more references to the object.