# How to log all stdin, stdout and std err from InteractiveConsole in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, stdin

I am trying to copy all stdio to a logfile. I have tried the solution presented in this question because the question is similar to mine:
[How to log everything that occurs in a Python interactive shell session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053900/how-to-log-everything-that-occurs-in-a-python-interactive-shell-session)

However the solution in the question above does not work in newer versions of python.

My goal is to start an interactive shell via `code.InteractiveConsole` and log all stdio. I also need the tty commands to work. I have found that when I have both the interactive shell and stdio redirect implemented, I lose tty. i.e. arrow keys print escape characters, `ctl+d` no longer exits the shell.

Here is my current code:

```
from io import TextIOWrapper
import sys
import code
import atexit


class StdIn(TextIOWrapper):

    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def read(self, size=-1):
        msg = sys.__stdin__.read(size)
        sys.__stdin__.flush()
        # self.logger.log.info(msg.rstrip())
        self.logger.write(msg.rstrip())
        self.logger.flush()
        return msg

    def readline(self):
        msg = sys.__stdin__.readline()
        # sys.__stdin__.flush()
        self.logger.write(msg)
        self.logger.flush()
        return msg

    def get_input(self, prompt):
        # sys.__stdin__.flush()
        sys.stdout.write(sys.ps1)
        msg = self.readline()
        return msg

    def fileno(self):
        return sys.__stdin__.fileno()

    def istty(self):
        return sys.__stdin__.isatty()

    @property
    def errors(self):
        return sys.__stdin__.errors

    @property
    def encoding(self):
        return sys.__stdin__.encoding

class StdOut:

    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def write(self, s):
        res = sys.__stdout__.write(s)
        sys.__stdout__.flush()
        self.logger.write(s)
        self.logger.flush()
        return res

    def fileno(self):
        return sys.__stdout__.fileno()

    @property
    def errors(self):
        return sys.__stdout__.errors

    @property
    def encoding(self):
        return sys.__stdout__.encoding

class StdErr:

    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def write(self, s):
        res = sys.__stderr__.write(s)
        sys.__stderr__.flush()
        self.logger.write(s)
        self.logger.flush()
        return res

    def fileno(self):
        return sys.__stderr__.fileno()

    @property
    def errors(self):
        return sys.__stderr__.errors

    @property
    def encoding(self):
        return sys.__stderr__.encoding

def start_up():
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    sys.stdin = sys.__stdin__
    sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__

def clean_up(logger):
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    sys.stdin = sys.__stdin__
    sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
    logger.write("end\n")
    logger.flush()
    logger.close()




from pprint import pprint
start_up()
logger = open("console_output.txt", "w")
atexit.register(clean_up, logger=logger)
logger.write("start\n")
logger.flush()


sys.stdin  = StdIn(logger)
sys.stdout = StdOut(logger)
sys.stderr = StdErr(logger)

console = code.InteractiveConsole(locals=dict(globals(), **locals()))
console.raw_input = sys.stdin.get_input
console.interact()
```

I used the linux command `script` to log the console(this option wont always be available which is why I'm trying to log everything via python):

```
(pve) python console_loogger.py

Python 3.7.5 (default, Feb 10 2021, 16:08:16)
[GCC 9.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>>
>>> print(123)
123
>>> ^[[A
  File "<console>", line 1
    [A
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print("next try ctrl+d")
next try ctrl+d
>>> >>>
>>> exit()
```

here is the output from the python log:

```
>>> 
>>> print(123)
123
>>> [A
  File "<console>", line 1
    [A
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print("next try ctrl+d")
next try ctrl+d
>>> >>> 
>>> exit()
end
```

My intention is to eventually replace the file writes with calls to my logging software but this is a prototype to get the basic workings.

Notes:

I have also tried not redefining the `InteractiveConsole.raw_input` function. In those cases I found that no `stdin` was being logged at all. My `readline` function was never called.

Short version of my problem:
I am trying to log all standard in, out and error messages from code.InteractioveConsole to a file. A similar question was asked previously but the solution no longer applies to python 3.

Comment: Which operating system? On a unix-like system, you may find an external utility like `screen` does the job.

Comment: I can't really think of a reason why to do this, but if needs be, using something like a Jupyter notebook (in a purely linear fashion) might do it. It will save all input, output and errors in the notebook file.

Comment: OS is RHEL7. External utilities are tricky. The output is often difficult to read and does not contain timestamps. Its not automatically started. and it can be difficult to start up external utilities before a debugger.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.