# How to save console input and output in Python

Tags: python

How do I save my console input and output in Python so I can open it and work on it again later? Is there a better way to edit my code than in the console window?

I've tried converting it to HTML, but that didn't work. Saving it as a python file doesn't save my console input and output. Is there another way which makes it easier for me to edit my code? I'm working in Spyder (anaconda3) using Python.

Comment: I think you should use [jupyter notebook](http://jupyter.org/install).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log everything that occurs in a Python interactive shell session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053900/how-to-log-everything-that-occurs-in-a-python-interactive-shell-session)

Comment: "Is there a better way to edit my code than in the console window?" Yes. The simplest solution is to not write code in the console. Write it in a proper code window and then test it in the shell. Nothing beyond brief snippets of test code really belongs in the interactive shell.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I truly appreciate it, and I've managed to figure it out now! c: